# Why can't a Double value stored as Object in NSUserDefault is not reflected in UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, nsuserdefaults, uialertview

I am trying to store `Double` Value in `NSUserDefault` But though i am able to store it (as my NSLog value shows true value), when I tried to reload UITableView, its Cell value is not updated with current value in userdefault.

This weird behavior happens only when i call my **`setUserDefaults`** method from delegate method of `UIAlertView`

Why such weird behavior happens??

Here is my code:

```
- (void)setUserDefaults
{
    NSLog(@"setUserDefault : empArray: %d, empCount: %d",empArray.count, empCount);
    NSMutableDictionary *empData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if (empArray.count>1)
        empData = [empArray objectAtIndex:(empCount-1)];   // because empCount starts from 1. and empArray[0] = empCount 1
    else
        empData = [empArray objectAtIndex:0];

    [userDefault setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[empData objectForKey:@"salary"]] forKey:@"salary"];
    NSLog(@"setUserDefaults: salary=%.2f",[[empData objectForKey:@"salary"] doubleValue]);

    [empData release];

    [self.tblView reloadData];
}
```

Delegate method of UIAlertView goes as below:

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 1)    // btnRemoveEmpPressed. 
    {
        if(buttonIndex==0)
        {
            NSLog(@"buttonIndex 0");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"empRemovedPressed OK, buttonIndex 1, empArray Count %d, empCount %d",empArray.count, empCount);
            //        [empArray removeObjectAtIndex:(empCount)];
            empCount -= 1;
            lblTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Employee %d",empCount];
            [self setUserDefaults];
        }
//        [tblView reloadData];
    }
    else if (alertView.tag == 2)
    {
        if (buttonIndex==1)
        {
            [self resetUserDefaults];
            empCount = 1;
            [empArray removeAllObjects];
            lblTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Employee %d",empCount];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show cellForRowAtIndexPath code as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You aren't using `doubleValue` when setting user defaults. Either do that or, as herz says, use the `setDouble` method.
- You aren't calling `synchronize` on your defaults object after updating it
- Don't release empData, you didn't retain it
- I'm assuming `userDefault` is set up elsewhere and it is not `nil` when you are using it?

Comment: i am using alloc init for empData, so i believe i am retaining empData. Also i am sure that i have set up userDefaults properly and not having nil value. But i will try use synchronize...

Comment: You shouldn't be alloc/init ing it, sorry, didnt notice that part of the code. You get the actual object from the array so you have a memory leak there. You don't need the alloc/init or release.

Comment: I tried using synchronize but no success. Also if I want to store Double value in userDefault as Object, Is it possible?? Because I am making Double Value to String and then storing it in user default??

Comment: ok thankz i got the answer based on your suggestions... but one more mistake done by me is in `[userDefault setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[empData objectForKey:@"salary"]] forKey:@"salary"];` line where it should have to be like  `[userDefault setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[[empData objectForKey:@"salary"] doubleValue]] forKey:@"salary"];`

Comment: The leak part is because you're initializing the array and later setting an autorelease object, which makes you lose the first reference and turns it into a leak, and later on trying to release the autorelease value, weird you didn't say it crashed there.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the `setDouble:forKey:` method of `NSUserDefaults` and let it manage the value for you. Also `synchronize` the `NSUserDefaults` in order to save the value for later usage.